# What is changing when adding element in a linkedlist?

Tags: java, linked-list

In LinkedList, when accessing the next node, my teacher used the following apporach:

```
public class LinkedList<T>{

    private Node<T> header;

    private int size;

    public LinkedList(){
        this.header=null;
        this.size=0;
    }
    public void add(T element){
            if(header==null){
                header= new Node<T>(element);
            }
            else{
                Node<T> current= header; 
                while(current.getNext()!=null){
                    current=current.getNext();

                }
                current.setNext(new Node<T>(element));
                size++;
            }
        }
}
```

It has been confused me for a while that in the snippet, it seems we are only operating on the new `current`node created within the method to traverse through the list and add elements. Then what actually makes the instance variable `this.header`changed? Thanks!

Comment: Well for starters, when `header` is `null` it is changed to point to the first element.  You see that, yes?

Comment: *Then what actually makes the instance variable this.headerchanged*: nothing. When adding a new element to a list, the header stays unchanged. The new element is added at the end of the list, not at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in following snippet `header` variable is set when you add the first element

```
if(header==null){
     header= new Node<T>(element);
 }
```

In subsequent calls to `add` method you are first setting value of `current` to  `header`  ( `current` points to the same location in memory which `header` also points to). When you traverse in list using `current` variable you are actually traversing the object you stored initially using `header`

On reaching the last node this code adds new element as a next node. scope of `current` variable is within your else block. However, you can always fetch your latest list using variable `header`